# show div while input is selected using css without javascript

Tags: html, css

My question is if anyway when I start to write in the input, not disappear if i slide my mouse out of the ".box" div.

Wonder if any selector or possible way to do without any Javascript.

Here is the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/vzRqY/

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="overlay"><input/></div>
LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM <br/>
LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it requires you to rearrange where the `input` is, but [it can be done](http://jsfiddle.net/vzRqY/2/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
    <input/>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM <br/>
LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box{
    background : red;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}
.overlay{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;    
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.box input {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 50%;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.box:hover .overlay,
.box:hover input,
.box input:focus,
.box input:focus + .overlay
{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Was what i desire, so the solution was in thinking outside the box. :)

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues--Oh, well put! If I could give you +10 rep for the remark, I would :-).

Comment: Just wondering can you do a form? Instead do a div with a lot input. when one selected it keeps the form? http://jsfiddle.net/vzRqY/9/ -> can you do for this case?

Comment: I cannot think of how to get a flawless `form` working. [This is as close as I could get](http://jsfiddle.net/vzRqY/25/), but _later inputs cannot keep earlier inputs from disappearing_ if the mouse moves out of the box.

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues--sorry, forgot to target your name in my last comment.

Comment: Thanks.. probably JS is the only solution no??

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues--maybe. I have a thought, but I would need to know two things: 1) how is the form intended to go away? Once activated, is it basically required that entry be made? 2) do other elements on the page need to be interacted with when the form is visible?

Comment: Well would like to do or just on focus out or leave the mouse leave the area. But if is simpler just disappear when someone click close or login button.

No sure what you mean other element interacted.

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues--well, obviously you don't want it to go away with "the mouse leave the area" as you said, because that was the original problem to solve. It seems "focus" or not is your main goal. What I meant by other elements interact, is whether one could still click on something outside the form area when the form is up.

Comment: well if you can use any solution in the fiddle in my first example with JS I appreciated. Later can always try to check before mouse leave if any element is focus.

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues--[Here is a changed css](http://jsfiddle.net/vzRqY/34/) that "expands" the area of the `form` outside the `box` perimeter. So a mouse move outside the expanded area still closes the `form`, but it gives the user more "play" in allowing some movement beyond the original box. Maybe this can be made to meet your needs but keep it pure css.

Comment: Thanks for that solution ... but i guess will ask for javascript solution. CSS will not help :/ is a very interaction website

Answer (score -2):

There is a specification in the works that would allow something like this:

```
.box &.overlay input:focus
```

This selector will match if the input box has focus (ie. is being typed in), but the styles will affect the `.overlay` (which is what you need to make it visible).

Unfortunately, few if any browsers support this feature yet...

Comment: did you try in the example? Any documentation for that?