# contactform in a dropdownmenu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, contact-form

I i have tried to use a contactform in a dropdownmenu. So far, so good i can use it in a menu, but i can't write anything in this contactform.

The menu closes every time. I have tried it with `display:block` but that does not work. What can i do to fix this problem. Solutions?

Here is a exception of my code:

```
          <li class="dropdown">
              <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="index.html">Kontakt <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="nav-header">Kontaktiere mich</li>
                    <li class="contactform">
                        <section>
                            <form method="post" action="/" class="contactbox">
                                <div class="contactbox">
                                    <p><label>Dein Anliegen:</label><br>
                                    <textarea class="input-xsmall" id="textarea" rows="3"></textarea>

                                    <p><label>Dein Name:</label><br>
                                    <input type="text" required=""></p>

                                    <p><label>Deine E-Mail-Adresse:</label><br>
                                    <input type="email" required="" value=""></p>

                                    <button class="btn" type="submit">absenden</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </section>
                    </li>
                </ul>
          </li>
```

Comment: I'm not certain this can be done entirely with css. It has some similarities to [this issue I helped solve](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044403/show-div-while-input-is-selected-using-css-without-javascipt/10044553#10044553), but with some other complicating factors. We need to see your css code as well and ideally for you to set up a [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) test case to play with solutions on.

Comment: It can be done using only CSS. One method is in my answer. There is also the option of using a checkbox or a radio button instead of a link, the :checked pseudo-class and sibling selectors :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a little change to the link on which you click to open the bottom:

```
<a data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="1" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
    Kontakt <b class="caret"></b>
</a>
```

and have this in the CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu {display: none;}

.dropdown-toggle:active + .dropdown-menu, 
.dropdown-toggle:focus + .dropdown-menu, 
.dropdown-menu:hover {display: block;}

.dropdown-toggle:focus {outline:none;}
```

**Note**: the drop-down opens when clicking Kontakt . If you wish it to open on hover as well, you need to have

```
.dropdown-toggle:hover + .dropdown-menu, 
.dropdown-toggle:active + .dropdown-menu,
.dropdown-toggle:focus + .dropdown-menu, 
.dropdown-menu:hover {display: block;}
```

As noted in the comments, this method has a problem: after clicking inside the drop-down and then moving the cursor outside the drop-down... it closes. This cannot be fixed, but there is...

---

... another way to do it: using a checkbox with a label instead of a link

```
<input data-toggle="dropdown" type='checkbox' name='dropdown-toggle' id='dropdown-toggle' class='dropdown-toggle'/>
<label for='dropdown-toggle'>Kontakt <b class="caret"></b></label>
```

In which case, the CSS would be:

```
.dropdown-toggle, .dropdown-menu {display: none;}
.dropdown-toggle:checked ~ .dropdown-menu, .dropdown-menu:hover {display: block;}
.dropdown-toggle:focus {outline:none;}
```

Demo http://dabblet.com/gist/2794382

Comment: Thank you! :-) one little problem still: When i click into a label and then go outside with the curosr, the menu still closes.

Comment: This gets close to a solution (and was along the lines of what I was thinking). I experience one bug with it (in Firefox, don't know about others). If you click in an `input` field, then move the mouse to the left past the "Kontakt" (no click, just moving) it disappears.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's normal. The drop-down has display: block as long as the Kontakt button has focus or the mouse cursor. The only way to fix that is not to use a link - I'll make a demo of that as well.